# List of unit statistics?

Tags: dune-2

Can someone please provide a list of unit statistics from Dune 2? Including things such as:

- Health
- Attack power
- Armor (and how it works)
- Range

The ones I've found online are useless as they are lifted straight from the manual - e.g. attack power for Sardaukar listed as "classified".

I know that I can find out myself by finding a unit editor, but the answer could be useful for future visitors and is definitely more convenient!

Also, is it correct that there's no attack type in Dune 2, i.e. all units do the same damage (armor notwithstanding) to each other, based solely on their attack power?

Comment: Argh! Wish I never saw this question. Now I want to play Dune 2 again...

Comment: @NickBayley If you do, try [Dune Dynasty](http://dunedynasty.sourceforge.net). It has modern enhancements such as build queues, high resolution and box select.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although you have now doomed me to definitely try it, because the lack of modern enhancements was going to be the other thing stopping me ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Stats]
"Shield" – hitpoints, "range" – weapon range, "arms" – weapon damage.

---

> Also, is it correct that there's no attack type in Dune 2, i.e. all units do the same damage (armor notwithstanding) to each other, based solely on their attack power?

Yes, there is no damage type.

> Armor (and how it works)

There is no armor in Dune 2.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of info I was looking for. Where did you get it? I had two questions: 1. I thought troopers had a longer range rocket attack that did less damage, are the stats for the short range "machine gun" attack? 2. Sonic tanks' range is affected by game speed (at least on DOS afaik), are its stats for the medium game speed?

Comment: @congusbongus this: http://ledmeister.com/dunexref.htm

Comment: Please note that these numbers are for the Sega Genesis US version of the game.

Comment: Actually, Sonic Tanks can be thought as doing special damage, the kind to which they have 100% immunity. But single "sonic dmg vs Sonic Tank = 0" is not quite comparable to what people mean by "damage types" today.

Answer (score 1):

These are stats taken from the PC version of Dune, EU v1.07, by parsing the output of [Dune II Editor](http://forum.dune2k.com/topic/19114-dune-ii-editor-with-107-support/).

```
+--------------+------+-----+------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     Name     |  HP  | Sgt | Cost | B/T | F/2 | Inacc | Speed | T/S | RoF | Rng | Dmg |
+--------------+------+-----+------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Carryall     |  100 |   0 |  800 |  64 | No  | No    |   200 |   3 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| 'Thopter     |   25 |   5 |  600 |  96 | Yes | No    |   150 |   2 |  50 |  50 |  50 |
| Infantry     |   50 |   1 |  100 |  32 | Yes | No    |     5 |   3 |  45 |   2 |   3 |
| Troopers     |  110 |   1 |  200 |  56 | Yes | No    |    10 |   3 |  50 |   5 |   5 |
| Soldier      |   20 |   1 |   60 |  32 | No  | No    |     8 |   3 |  45 |   2 |   3 |
| Trooper      |   45 |   1 |  100 |  56 | No  | No    |    15 |   3 |  50 |   5 |   5 |
| Saboteur     |   10 |   1 |  120 |  48 | No  | No    |    40 |   3 |  45 |   2 |   2 |
| Launcher     |  100 |   5 |  450 |  72 | Yes | No    |    30 |   1 | 120 |   9 |  75 |
| Deviator     |  120 |   5 |  750 |  80 | No  | No    |    30 |   1 | 180 |   7 |   0 |
| Tank         |  200 |   3 |  300 |  64 | No  | No    |    25 |   1 |  80 |   4 |  25 |
| Siege Tank   |  300 |   4 |  600 |  96 | Yes | No    |    20 |   1 |  90 |   5 |  30 |
| Devastator   |  400 |   4 |  800 | 104 | Yes | No    |    10 |   1 | 100 |   5 |  40 |
| Sonic Tank   |  110 |   4 |  600 | 104 | No  | No    |    30 |   1 |  80 |   8 |  60 |
| Trike        |  100 |   2 |  150 |  40 | Yes | No    |    45 |   2 |  50 |   3 |   5 |
| Raider Trike |   80 |   2 |  150 |  40 | Yes | No    |    60 |   2 |  50 |   3 |   5 |
| Quad         |  130 |   2 |  200 |  48 | Yes | No    |    40 |   2 |  50 |   3 |   7 |
| Harvester    |  150 |   2 |  300 |  64 | No  | No    |    20 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| MCV          |  150 |   2 |  900 |  80 | No  | No    |    20 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| Death Hand   |   70 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | No    |   250 |   2 |   0 |  15 | 100 |
| Rocket       |   70 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | Yes   |   200 |   2 |   0 |   8 |  75 |
| ARocket      |   70 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | No    |   160 |   8 |   0 |  60 |  75 |
| GRocket      |   70 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | Yes   |   200 |   2 |   0 |   7 |  75 |
| MiniRocket   |   70 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | No    |   180 |   5 |   0 |   3 |   0 |
| Bullet       |    1 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | No    |   250 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| Sonic Blast  |    1 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | No    |   200 |   0 |   0 |  10 |  25 |
| Sandworm     | 1000 |   0 |    0 |   0 | No  | No    |    35 |   3 |  20 |   0 | 300 |
+--------------+------+-----+------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I've abbreviated column headers to keep the table smaller:

- Sgt = sight range
- B/T = build time
- F/2 = fires twice?
- Inacc = is inaccurate?
- T/S = turn speed
- RoF = rate of fire
- Rng = range
- Dmg = damage